# Timer not stopping after button is pressed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I have a timer i press a button to start it and press a button to stop it but the button used to stop the timer does not work, i tried dispose,stop and enabled=false,all of them did not worked.The timer continues to send telegram messages even though i pressed stop. Frontend is a aspx form.

```
Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer

Public Function TelegramSendMessage(ByVal apilToken As String, ByVal destID As String, ByVal text As String) As String
        Dim a As String = apilToken
        Dim urlString As String = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + apilToken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + destID + "&text=" + text
        Dim webclient As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Return webclient.DownloadString(urlString)
    End Function

Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        TelegramSendMessage(yourtoken,destinationid , "hi")
    End Sub

 Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        aTimer.AutoReset = True
        aTimer.Interval = 60000 
        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
        aTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

Protected Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        'aTimer.Dispose()
        'aTimer.Enabled = False
        aTimer.Stop()
        


    End Sub
```

Comment: `Timer` is not going to work because a webpage is stateless. Once the page is send to the client everything is recycled, including the timer, so it does nothing while the user is on the page. You might want to rethink your design and/or use something like [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: You can save the time right before page loads in a HiddenField.  On button click, get that time and parse it to an DateTime object and then figure out how long has elapsed.  It's not pretty.